# Make a ground mask raster with the Greater Than tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem, elevation, lidar

I'm trying to see if I can replicate the Esri solar suitability site example [from this article](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/1010/solarsiting.html).

I fail on the creation of the binary ground raster. I have made a Bare Earth raster from LiDAR ground points, and a surface raster from LiDAR first return points. The tool I use is **Greater Than** with first return as input raster 1, and ground raster as input raster 2.

I expect a raster with value 1 where the input1 raster is greater than the input2 raster, and value 0 where it is not greater. However, this is the result after the two input rasters:

[image: Input1 - DSM (first return)]

[image: Input2 - Raster of Ground points]

[image: Result of Greater Than tool]

The result should be a ground mask raster like this picture:

[image]

---

Okay, I have the raster I want after doing raster calc + 5 for the DTM and then using a CON expression concerning the DTM and DSM in raster calc to get the ground points raster.

Comment: Have you tried a Con() statement in raster calculator? e.g. `Con(first_return_dem > bare_earth_dem, 1, 0)`

Answer (score 2):

The tool is probably working perfectly -- if the vast majority of the surface (DSM) is greater than the bare earth (DEM), even if only by a few centimeters, the result raster looks correct.

Looking at the ESRI article, however, their ground mask wasn't just "greater than":

> assigning a value of 1 for any cell greater than or equal to the **bare earth value plus five feet** and assigning 0 to all others, which were ground cells

What you therefore need to do is create a raster of the DEM plus five feet (or whatever threshold you want to establish for your own project), using [Plus](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000096000000) or [Raster Calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000z7000000). Then, try running [GreaterThan](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000m5000000) again.

Comment: I didn't know I had to establish a threshold, I thought the plus 5 feet was already an embedded value as a 5ft DEM, but I'll try the plus tool.